# Button not displaying text after update using button.setTextColor

Tags: android, android-button

I have a scenario where I need to inspect a setting and then adjust the color of the text in three buttons situated side by side. I also change the icon being shown and the background color on the buttons. Both of those things work perfectly, but the text itself no longer displays after I change the color. Initially it's just fine when I don't call setTextColor.

Here is the layout I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".ui.SelectSportActivity">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/select_sport"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/logo_with_name"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/my_logo" />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/choose_your_sport"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"

    />
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/imageview_red_gray_border"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/cricket_icn_select"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:id="@+id/cricketButton"
                android:paddingTop="32sp"
                android:paddingLeft="52sp"
                android:paddingRight="52sp"
                android:paddingBottom="32sp"
                android:drawablePadding="5sp"
                android:text="@string/cricket"/>
        <Button
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/imageview_white_gray_border"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/softball_icn"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/softballButton"
                android:paddingTop="32sp"
                android:paddingLeft="52sp"
                android:paddingRight="52sp"
                android:paddingBottom="32sp"
                android:drawablePadding="5sp"
                android:text="@string/softball"/>
        <Button
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/imageview_white_gray_border"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/tennis_icn"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/tennisButton"
                android:paddingTop="32sp"
                android:paddingLeft="52sp"
                android:paddingRight="52sp"
                android:paddingBottom="32sp"
                android:drawablePadding="5sp"
                android:text="@string/tennis"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The code checks a value then adjusts as needed by calling this function:

```
private fun toggleButtons(sport: Int) {

    when (sport) {
        0 -> {
            cricketButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_red_gray_border)
            cricketButton.drawable(R.drawable.cricket_icn_select)
            cricketButton.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF)
            softballButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_white_gray_border)
            softballButton.drawable(R.drawable.softball_icn)
            softballButton.setTextColor(0x000000)
            tennisButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_white_gray_border)
            tennisButton.drawable(R.drawable.tennis_icn)
            tennisButton.setTextColor(0x000000)
        }
        1 -> {
            cricketButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_white_gray_border)
            cricketButton.drawable(R.drawable.cricket_icn)
            cricketButton.setTextColor(0x000000)
            softballButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_red_gray_border)
            softballButton.drawable(R.drawable.softball_icn_select)
            softballButton.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF)
            tennisButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_white_gray_border)
            tennisButton.drawable(R.drawable.tennis_icn)
            tennisButton.setTextColor(0x000000)
        }
        2 -> {
            cricketButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_white_gray_border)
            cricketButton.drawable(R.drawable.cricket_icn)
            cricketButton.setTextColor(0x000000)
            softballButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_white_gray_border)
            softballButton.drawable(R.drawable.softball_icn)
            softballButton.setTextColor(0x000000)
            tennisButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_red_gray_border)
            tennisButton.drawable(R.drawable.tennis_icn_select)
            tennisButton.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF)
        }
        else -> {
            Timber.w("Unknown sport selected: $sport")
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after playing around with it there were two things wrong. One silly (unlike in xml, setTextColor needs a resolved ID, not the RGB) and you cannot use .drawable in the code. Needs to be setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds.

```
            cricketButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_white_gray_border)
            cricketButton.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black, null))
            cricketButton.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.cricket_icn,0,0)
            softballButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_red_gray_border)
            softballButton.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white, null))
            softballButton.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.softball_icn_select,0,0)
            tennisButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.imageview_white_gray_border)
            tennisButton.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.black, null))
            tennisButton.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.tennis_icn,0,0)
```